Como realizar un query SELECT por partes cuando trae muchos registros con PreparedStatement en Java?
Tengo el siguiente código para obtener datos de un SELECT, pero esa tabla a la que consulto maneja un gran volumen de datos, y tarda demasiado tiempo o marca error, quisiera saber como puedo traer los registros que regresa el SELECT por partes y que se vayan guardando en la lista de tipo Employees
alguien sabe como puedo realizar eso?
Se me ocurre consultar el total de registros de la tabla e iterar el SELECT con un limit, pero no se si eso es correcto ni como seria
espero me puedan ayudar por favor
public void leerDatos() {
    String user = "postgres";
    String pss = "admin123";

    empleadoList = new ArrayList<>();
    Connection connect = null;
    PreparedStatement stm = null;
    ResultSet result = null;
    final int pageSize = 1000; // Tamaño de cada página
    int offset = 0;

    try {
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bd_test", user, pss);
        // Obtener el total de registros para controlar el ciclo
        PreparedStatement stmCount = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees");
        ResultSet resultCount = stmCount.executeQuery();
        int records = 0;
        if (resultCount.next()) {
            records = resultCount.getInt(1);
        }
        System.out.println("Total registros: " + records);

        // Leer datos por páginas
        while (offset < records) {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM employees LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";
            stm = connect.prepareStatement(query);
            stm.setInt(1, pageSize);
            stm.setInt(2, offset);
            result = stm.executeQuery();

            while (result.next()) {
                Employees empleado = new Employees();
                empleado.setId(result.getInt("id"));
                empleado.setFirstName(result.getString("first_name"));
                empleado.setLastName(result.getString("last_name"));
                empleado.setSalary(result.getDouble("salary"));
                empleadoList.add(empleado);
            }

            offset += pageSize; // Incrementar el offset para la siguiente página
        }

        if (!empleadoList.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Primer nombre en la lista: " + empleadoList.get(0).getFirstName());
           insertarDatos(empleadoList);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("SQL Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (result != null) result.close();
            if (stm != null) stm.close();
            if (connect != null) connect.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("SQL Error en cierre: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

y este es el metodo insertarDatos, el cual recibe una lista
//metodo para insertar datos a la tabla empleados_dup
    public void insertarDatos(List<Employees> empleList) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("ENTRA AL METODO INSERT   \n");

        String user = "postgres";
        String pss = "admin123";
        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bd_test", user, pss);
        PreparedStatement stm = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO empleados_duplicado (nombre_dup, apellido_dup, salario_dup) VALUES (?,?,?)");

        for (Employees empl : empleList) {
            stm.setString(1, empl.getFirstName());
            stm.setString(2, empl.getLastName());
            stm.setString(3, empl.getSalary());

        }
        stm.executeQuery();//executeBatch();

    }

pero manda el error y al consultar la tabla solo tiene agregado un registro

SQL Error: La consulta no retornó ningún resultado.


ya intento ponerle un  LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20 o algo similar?

@RuslanLópez  si a mi consulta le pongo un limit de 100 mil por ejemplo y la tabla tiene 1 millon de registros, como seria ahi? como le haria para traerme registros de 100 mil en 100 mil ?

¿Por que no lo intentas primero?

intenta dividir la consulta en múltiples "páginas" de resultados, procesándolos en bloques de un tamaño fijo (pageSize). Esto reduce la carga en la memoria y el tiempo de espera de la respuesta y también piensa usar LIMIT y OFFSET, éstos comandos SQL controlan cuántos registros se recuperan y desde qué punto empezar.
public void leerDatos() {
        String user = "postgres";
        String pss = "admin123";

        empleadoList = new ArrayList<>();
        Connection connect = null;
        PreparedStatement stm = null;
        ResultSet result = null;
        final int pageSize = 1000; // Tamaño de cada página
        int offset = 0;

        try {
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bd_test", user, pss);
            // Obtener el total de registros para controlar el ciclo
            PreparedStatement stmCount = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees");
            ResultSet resultCount = stmCount.executeQuery();
            int records = 0;
            if (resultCount.next()) {
                records = resultCount.getInt(1);
            }
            System.out.println("Total registros: " + records);

            // Leer datos por páginas
            while (offset < records) {
                String query = "SELECT * FROM employees LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";
                stm = connect.prepareStatement(query);
                stm.setInt(1, pageSize);
                stm.setInt(2, offset);
                result = stm.executeQuery();

                while (result.next()) {
                    Employees empleado = new Employees();
                    empleado.setId(result.getInt("id"));
                    empleado.setFirstName(result.getString("first_name"));
                    empleado.setLastName(result.getString("last_name"));
                    empleado.setSalary(result.getDouble("salary"));
                    empleadoList.add(empleado);
                }

                offset += pageSize; // Incrementar el offset para la siguiente página
            }

            if (!empleadoList.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Primer nombre en la lista: " + empleadoList.get(0).getFirstName());
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("SQL Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (result != null) result.close();
                if (stm != null) stm.close();
                if (connect != null) connect.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println("SQL Error en cierre: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }


muchas gracias, si me funciono, tengo una duda, debo de insertar esos datos obtenidos en otra tabla, para ello hice otro metodo que recibe una lista y que realice el insert, ese metodo lo mando a llamar dentro del metodo leerDatos(), dentro del if donde se valida que la lista no este vacia, y lo hice de la siguiente manera, actualizo mi pregunta, pero me manda el error:   SQL Error: La consulta no retornó ningún resultado. y consulto la tabla y solo tiene un registro agregado
